# store cascading dropdown in json file ready for asp.net code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, cascading

I have a project I'm working, there are 2 dropdown lists.

The first drop-down is populated using $.getJSON to get the parent dropdown data when the drop-down is .change this will get the second dropdown list of data.

whatever is selected in the dropdown lists it can be added to a div, the selection is separated with "."

[The screenshot isn't great, but what it shows is there are two parent Down-downs selected and saved in the div

from each of those two parent down-downs there are 2 selections in the div below it.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK40r.png)

I can use ajax to POST the data in each of the divs to asp.net code behind, however, the issue I am having I would never know which parent goes with the child. I'm sure there is a better solution to my problem.

Maybe when I add the parent or child to the div to stores both parent and child selection somewhere and when I click the button i will get the parent and child selection in the code behind.

I apologize in advance if my description doesn't make sense, if you want more information please let me know.

I'm trying to find the best solution for posting my parent and child selections to asp.net code behind so I can do something with that data.

Many thanks

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: `code`
if ($("#dlIndustrySector option:selected").val() != "") {
$("#tdIndustryBasket").append($("#dlIndustrySector option:selected").text());
frmIndustryID = $("#dlIndustrySector option:selected").val();
numIndustries++;}
`code`

#tdIndustryBasket is just an empty div

`code`
var selectedCatBasketItems = $('#tdCategoriesBasket').text();
$.ajax({
url: 'MyDetails.aspx/btn_updateExpertisePref_Click',
type: "POST",
data: "{'GivenCatBasketItems':'" + selectedCatBasketItems + "'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
})
`code`

Comment: I am not able to read code in comments. Please edit your question and include code there. Also, I suggest you read this : https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/